# How to override any specific style of a bootstrap class in Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having an HTML element

```
<div [style.color]="themeService.backgroundColor" class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
            <ul class="pagination" id="pag-bar">
              <li class="page-item2" *ngIf="!getStyle(1)">
                <span class="spl" id="left-arrow" (click)="decPresentPage()">
                  <div class="arrow" (click)="decreasePage()">
                      &lt;
                    </div>
                      <div class="side-text">Previous</div>
                </span>
              </li>
              <li class="page-item">
                <span class="page-link" href="#" (click)="decPresentPage()">
                  <div class="page-text prev">S</div>
                  <br/>
                </span>
              </li>
              <li class="page-item" *ngFor="let num of getNumber(maxPage)">
                <span class="page-link" *ngIf="presentPage>=4 && presentPage-3+num<=noOfPages" [class.active_page]="getStyle(presentPage-3+num)"
                  (click)="getPresentPage(presentPage-3+num)" href="#">
                  <div [class.active_page]="getStyle(presentPage-3+num)" class="page-text">U</div>
                  <span class="page-number">{{presentPage-3+num}}</span>
                </span>
                <span class="page-link" *ngIf="presentPage<4 && num<=noOfPages" [class.active_page]="num+1 == presentPage" (click)="getPresentPage(num+1)"
                  href="#">
                  <div [class.active_page]="num+1 == presentPage" class="page-text">U</div>
                  <span class="page-number">{{num+1}}</span>
                </span>
              </li>
              <li class="page-item">
                <span class="page-link" (click)="incPresentPage()">
                  <div class="page-text next">SPER</div>
                </span>
              </li>
              <div class="next-page-mobile">Page {{count}}</div>
              <li class="page-item2" *ngIf="!getStyle(noOfPages)">
                <span class="spl" (click)="incPresentPage()">
                  <div class="arrow" (click)="increasePage()">&gt;</div>
                  <div class="side-text">Next</div>
                </span>
              </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
```

I want to set its styling using a service but the styling is overridden by bootstrap class. I tried to rewrite the bootstrap class in `.css` file but it is disturbing style. How can I stop bootstrap to set `color` style and rest all style should be retained. I also tried to change the style by selecting that class element in theme service using `(document.getElementsByClassName("pagination")[0] as HTMLElement).style.background = '#373737';` but `(document.getElementsByClassName("pagination")[0]` is undefined when page is loaded.

Comment: Your `style.color` tag is on the div, but your code gets the class for the `ul`. Which one are you trying to change? Also, the property you're using is `themService.backgroundColor`, but you're changing the `color` style property, i.e. the text color, not the background color

Comment: Let me try it with `[style.background-color]` .

Comment: It is not working

Comment: I want to change `background-color` of every thing inside `div` tag.

Comment: Can you create a StackBlitz that reproduces the issue please?

Comment: @user184994 I solved it actually I wrote `[style.background-color]="themeService.backgroundColor"` for all inner elements. Should I answer it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it actually I wrote `[style.background-color]="themeService.backgroundColor"` for all inner elements.

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
                <ul class="pagination" id="pag-bar">
                  <li class="page-item2" *ngIf="!getStyle(1)">
                    <span [style.background-color]='themeService.backgroundColor' class="spl" id="left-arrow" (click)="decPresentPage()">
                      <div class="arrow" (click)="decreasePage()">
                          &lt;
                        </div>
                          <div class="side-text">Previous</div>
                    </span>
                  </li>
                  <li class="page-item">
                    <span [style.background-color]='themeService.backgroundColor' class="page-link" href="#" (click)="decPresentPage()">
                      <div class="page-text prev">S</div>
                      <br/>
                    </span>
                  </li>
                  <li class="page-item" *ngFor="let num of getNumber(maxPage)">
                    <span [style.background-color]='themeService.backgroundColor' class="page-link" *ngIf="presentPage>=4 && presentPage-3+num<=noOfPages" [class.active_page]="getStyle(presentPage-3+num)"
                      (click)="getPresentPage(presentPage-3+num)" href="#">
                      <div [class.active_page]="getStyle(presentPage-3+num)" class="page-text">U</div>
                      <span class="page-number">{{presentPage-3+num}}</span>
                    </span>
                    <span [style.background-color]='themeService.backgroundColor' class="page-link" *ngIf="presentPage<4 && num<=noOfPages" [class.active_page]="num+1 == presentPage" (click)="getPresentPage(num+1)"
                      href="#">
                      <div [class.active_page]="num+1 == presentPage" class="page-text">U</div>
                      <span class="page-number">{{num+1}}</span>
                    </span>
                  </li>
                  <li class="page-item">
                    <span [style.background-color]='themeService.backgroundColor' class="page-link" (click)="incPresentPage()">
                      <div class="page-text next">SPER</div>
                    </span>
                  </li>
                  <div class="next-page-mobile">Page {{count}}</div>
                  <li class="page-item2" *ngIf="!getStyle(noOfPages)">
                    <span [style.background-color]='themeService.backgroundColor' class="spl" (click)="incPresentPage()">
                      <div class="arrow" (click)="increasePage()">&gt;</div>
                      <div class="side-text">Next</div>
                    </span>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
```